# How to make shell-command run using shell profile and current directory hooks (ex. direnv)

Tags: shell, process, comint, environment

I am trying to get `shell-command` and `async-shell-command` to integrate seamlessly with a couple of programs in my `.bashrc` file, specifically [direnv](http://direnv.net/) in this example.

I found that if I customized `shell-command-switch`, I could get shell processes to load my profile as if it were a regular interactive login shell:

```
(setq shell-command-switch (purecopy "-ic"))
(setq explicit-bash-args '("-ic" "export EMACS=; stty echo; bash"))
```

I am also using [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

Say I have a `~/.bashrc` file with:

```
...

eval "$(direnv hook $0)"
echo "foo"
```

Inside `~/code/foo` I have a `.envrc` file with:

```
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
echo "bar"
```

If I run `M-x shell` with `default-directory` set to `~/code/foo`, a bash shell will correctly load my profile and run the direnv hook to add that to my path:

```
direnv: loading .envrc
bar
direnv: export ~PATH
~/code/foo $ echo $PATH
/Users/username/code/foo/bin:/usr/local/bin:... # rest of $PATH
```

However if `default-directory` is still `~/code/foo` and I run `M-! echo $PATH`, it correctly loads my .bashrc but doesn't execute the direnv hook of the current directory:

```
foo
/usr/local/bin:... # rest of $PATH without ./bin
```

I get the same result if I run `M-! cd ~/code/foo && echo $PATH`.

Is there a way I can advise or hook into `shell-command` or `start-process` to make it behave as if it were being sent from an interactive shell buffer?

Comment: What does your direnv hook look like?  If it is defined in ~/.bashrc and you eval'd `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")` then it should be evaluated along with every other command in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: The line in my ~/.bashrc is `eval "$(direnv hook $0)"`. This is getting executed, but the mechanism that should get fired when you are in a specific directory with an `.envrc` file isn't.

Comment: Is nothing in the `.envrc` file evaluated?  Or is it just environment variables that are not exported?  Could you please provide a full example so that I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @rekado - Thanks for taking a look at it. I updated my question to be more explicit for reproducing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Rekado and Erik for pointing out how the direnv hook works by using `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. Since `shell-command` doesn't use a prompt, this wasn't getting executed.

While Erik's answer works in my example of calling a shell command with `M-!` with `default-directory` set, it wouldn't work in the following example:

```
(let ((default-directory "~/code/"))
  (shell-command "cd ~/code/foo && echo $PATH"))
```

After some googling, I [found a way to create a preexec hook](https://superuser.com/a/175802) in bash to execute something before a command is executed. I took this idea and modified to fit my need for direnv. Here's what the relevant part of my ~/.bashrc looks like now:

```
eval "$(direnv hook $0)"
direnv_preexec () {
  [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return # don't execute on completion
  [ "$BASH_COMMAND" \< "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't double execute on prompt hook
  eval "$(direnv export bash)"
}
trap "direnv_preexec && $BASH_COMMAND" DEBUG
```

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seem to be a problem with Emacs but with bash.  `shell-command` just executes `call-process` on the shell and passes arguments.  I tried this on a regular shell:

```
bash -ic "cd ~/code/foo && echo $PATH"
```

`~/.bashrc` is sourced, but the direnv hook is not run.  When `direnv hook bash` is executed, a function `_direnv_hook` is output and prepended to `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

```
_direnv_hook() {
  eval "$(direnv export bash)";
};
if ! [[ "$PROMPT_COMMAND" =~ _direnv_hook ]]; then
  PROMPT_COMMAND="_direnv_hook;$PROMPT_COMMAND";
fi
```

I suspect that `PROMPT_COMMAND` simply won't work.  That's not a problem, though, because the `_direnv_hook` is really simple.  We can simply prepend `eval $(direnv export bash)` to the shell command and it will work:

```
(let ((default-directory "~/code/foo/"))
  (shell-command "eval \"$(direnv export bash)\" && echo $PATH"))
```

This will print the augmented path to the messages buffer.  Alternatively, execute with `M-!`:

```
cd ~/code/foo && eval "$(direnv export bash)" && echo $PATH
```

You don't need to `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped put me on the right track. I was looking for a solution that doesn't involve adding the `eval "$(direnv export bash)"` in elisp, but this was extremely helpful and put me on the right path.

Answer (score 6):

Running `eval "$(direnv hook $0)"` defines a function that hooks into `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is never called when bash is run as `bash -ic` because there is no prompt. You can change the line:

`eval "$(direnv hook $0)"`

to:

`eval "$(direnv hook $0)" && _direnv_hook`

to explicitly call the hook function.

Edit: Just realized rekado gave a very similar answer.

Comment: This is the most concise answer pointing out my unfamiliarity with how direnv works with `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Answer (score 3):

nowadays you would likely want to use https://github.com/wbolster/emacs-direnv

it works similar to the hook that direnv installs in your shell. the emacs environment is updated on request (or automatically when switching buffers) to match what direnv states is the correct environment for the current directory.

by modifying `exec-path` and `process-environment` emacs will behave like your shell would do: execute programs from the right paths and with the right environment.